# Is there a JavaScript / Jquery Component which creates a workspace like in Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently searching for a Jquery (or native JavaScript) component which creates a "workspace" experience similar to the eclipse workspace. I tried JQuery UI Layout but this doesn't fit my needs. Searching the web did not gain any suitable results.

- I'd like to divide a page into frames (regions) which can be:

  - opened/closed
  - hidden/shown
  - pinned or unpinned (fixed or floating)
  - (in the best case, the frames can be reorganized by dragging them to other positions)
- The frames should be able to contain subframes
- And one important feature (which is not available in jquery ui layout): it should be possible to add single frames dynamicly.

Does anyone know a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/6-flexible-jquery-plugins-to-control-webpage-layouts-easily/
http://www.jquery.wisdomplug.com/jquery-plugins/11-best-jquery-layout-plugins/
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/layoutmanager

I guess these would help you much

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this won't help. Most of the frameworks found behind this links are layout-managers for layouting pages but without any dynamic functionality.