# Eclipse-like UI in JavaScript (with views, groups, etc)

Tags: javascript, eclipse, user-interface

I am looking for a JavaScript library that supports UI interactions similar to the workspace in the Eclipse IDE, i.e. that allows the user to

- split the screen up into different view groups that contain multiple views
- being able to resize those groups
- create new groups via drag and drop
- move views between groups
- minimizing/maximizing views

The views and an initial workspace setup should be predefined by the developer. While I could setup an initial layout and the views with say JQuery UI, I would like to enable these interactions so the users can customize their workspace. This is along the lines of the question [Is there a JavaScript / Jquery Component which creates a workspace like in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153099/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-component-which-creates-a-workspace-like-in-eclip)

Is there a JavaScript library/framework that provides all these interactions out of the box (so that I only have to provide the views, but not implement workspace itself - similar to the Eclipse RCP)?

Comment: Look at GWT for example. But this isn't really the type of question that are fit for SO. You'll get many answer with none really the definite one that should be accepted.

Comment: if you find the answer somewhere else please post it here, I am searching for something similar for some time now

Comment: @dystroy Thanks - where would I ask such a question then? I have done something similar in GWT & agree that it's great for that purpose, but I want to implement it in plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at ExtJS, it has all the components you need for building something like this. Here's an example with different resizeable windows: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/portal/portal.html

Note that ExtJS is an enterprise product which might be not the best choice for you, depending on what you're trying to build.

ExtJS 4.1 Demos: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/#sample-16
EXtJS KitchenSink: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/kitchensink/index.html#basic-panel

Comment: Thanks - ExtJS looks great & is definitely one of the libraries I will consider if I will build such a workspace from components.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [RAP](http://www.eclipse.org/rap/).