# SonarQube version 5.1.2 user interface design

Tags: javascript, user-interface, reactjs, user-experience, sonarqube5.1

The user interface of SonarQube version 5.1.2 is well structured, concise and powerful. For instance, when looking at issues you have an indication of where you are in the set, you see the filter on your left.

This the best web UI I have ever used. Is there documentation about the high level concepts or abstractions that make up this UI? Is there a guide of the main implementation components (which is done using ReactJS)?

Like the post [Eclipse like ui in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195346/eclipse-like-ui-in-javascript-with-views-groups-etc), I am looking for a solution where users would use a unified UI with different perspectives rather than a plethora of different little apps.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the good feedback. You can inspire from the SonarQube UI, but there is no documentation/guide about it.

Comment: Understood. Is it possible to run the user interface without building a backend?

Comment: Currently that's not possible.